# Bootstrap and Grails 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, bootstrap-4

I'm building app using `Grails 3.3.11` also I'm using Bootstrap in some views , although the bootstrap files found in the `application.css` and `application.js` , I have to add this, to be able to see the bootstrap effect on my views :

```
<asset:javascript src="bootstrap.min.js"/>
    <asset:stylesheet src="bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

why is that? I'm using the bootstrap that was shipped with the Grails

here is the `application.css`:

```
*= require bootstrap
*= require bootstrap-grid
*= require bootstrap-reboot
*= require grails
*= require main
*= require mobile
*= require_self
```

here is the `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery-3.3.1.min
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap.bundle
//= require popper.min
//= require_self
```

Comment: It will depend - are you including application.js/css in your layout or view? if not they wont show up.

Comment: @erichelgeson , yes including both of them in the GSP